# How to share Azure Access Token between 2 separate process (exe) in windows?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, access-token, desktop-application

The current process is as follows :

1. I have one desktop application which have 2 exes, the first exe run and do some process, so a user log in using azure active directory interactive mode to log into managed instance.
   2.The first process before finishing send some data in command line and fire the second exe with those parameters
2. In command parameter i am sending the access token and expiry also, so that the new exe can also log into MI with that token.
   4 The problem starts when the token is expired, the application is unable to access token silently as there is no token in current cache, so it open the windows interactive screen again which client do not want.

```
Public Class ActiveDirectoryAuthProvider
    Inherits SqlAuthenticationProvider

    Private ReadOnly _clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Aptify.Services.Authentication.AzureAD.ClientID")
    Private ReadOnly _redirectUri As Uri = New Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Aptify.Services.Authentication.AzureAD.RedirectURI"))
    Private Shared _token As String
    Private Shared _expire As DateTimeOffset
    
    //These two properties as set when we parse the command line argument  
    Public Property Token As String
        Get
            Return _token
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _token = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Expire As DateTimeOffset
        Get
            Return _expire
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateTimeOffset)
            _expire = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Async Function AcquireTokenAsync(ByVal parameters As SqlAuthenticationParameters) As Task(Of SqlAuthenticationToken)

        Dim authContext As AuthenticationContext = New AuthenticationContext(parameters.Authority)
        authContext.CorrelationId = parameters.ConnectionId
        Dim result As AuthenticationResult
        Dim callInteractiveMethod As Boolean = False


        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Token) Then
            Try
                result = Await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(parameters.Resource, _clientId)
            Catch ex As Exception
                callInteractiveMethod = True
            End Try
            If callInteractiveMethod Then
                result = Await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(parameters.Resource, _clientId, _redirectUri, New PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto), New UserIdentifier(parameters.UserId, UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId))
            End If

            //When first time token will be acquired, setting these two properties so that we can access them and send as command line to next exe
            Me.Token = result.AccessToken
            Me.Expire = result.ExpiresOn
            Return New SqlAuthenticationToken(result.AccessToken, result.ExpiresOn)
        Else
            Return New SqlAuthenticationToken(Me.Token, Me.Expire)
        End If

    End Functiontype here
```

**

**Is there any way we can share the token and let second exe refresh token with acquire token silent async method ?**

Answer (score 0):

> You can share the token between two separate processes by using a shared cache.
>
> Using the `TokenCache` class you can store the token in a shared cache. The `TokenCache` class is a thread-safe cache that can be shared between multiple processes.

Steps to share the token between two separate processes:

> The Cache file should be stored on a network drive or a file share that both processes can access.

1. In the first process-
   Create a `TokenCache` object and set the `CacheStorageType` property to `TokenCachePersistenceType.Shared`. This will store the token in the shared cache.
2. When the first process starts, load the cache from the shared cache file using the `TokenCache.Deserialize` method.
3. Store the token in the cache using the `TokenCache.StoreToCache` method. When a token is acquired by the first process.

When the second process starts,

1. Load the cache from the shared cache file using the `TokenCache.Deserialize` method.
2. In this process, create a `TokenCache` object and set the `CacheStorageType` property to `TokenCachePersistenceType.Shared`. This will use the shared cache to acquire a token silently using the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method.

Code to use the `TokenCache` class to **share the token between two separate processes**

```vb
Dim cacheFile_Path As String = "\\server\sharePath\cache.bin"
Dim cache As TokenCache = New TokenCache()
cache.CacheStorageType = TokenCachePersistenceType.Shared
cache.Deserialize(File.ReadAllBytes(cacheFile_Path))

   Dim auth_Context As AuthenticationContext = New AuthenticationContext(authority, cache)
   Dim result As AuthenticationResult = Await auth_Context.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId)

 cache.StoreToCache(result)
 
' In the second process
Dim cacheFile_Path As String = "\\server\sharePath\cache.bin"
Dim cache As TokenCache = New TokenCache()
cache.CacheStorageType = TokenCachePersistenceType.Share    cache.Deserialize(File.ReadAllBytes(cacheFile_Path))
    Dim auth_Context As AuthenticationContext = New AuthenticationContext(authority, cache)
    Dim result As AuthenticationResult = Await auth_Context.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId)
```

For more information refer to [Refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token) and SO [Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461621/acquiretokensilent-is-failing-to-acquire-token-silently)

Comment: How are you using AcquireTokenSilentAsync in step one and DE-serializing the cache file when there is no token cached ? This is the first process, how we will get the token from cache ?

Comment: Also i cannot find TokenCache.CacheStorageType property in TokenCache class.

Comment: To cache the token in the first process, you can use the TokenCache class to store the token in a shared cache. You can use a Redis cache, a SQL Server cache, an Azure Cosmos DB cache, or any other cache implementing the IDistributedCache interface.

Comment: You can use the AddDistributedTokenCache method to add a distributed token cache to your application. You can use the AddStackExchangeRedisCache method to add a Redis cache, or the AddDistributedSqlServerCache method to add a SQL Server cache.
When you acquire the token in the first process, save the token to the cache using the TokenCache class. Check this [MSDoc.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization.md)